# How could time series prediction be applied in a real-time setting where it is infeasible to track every single item?

Tags: data-structures, statistics, probability, probability-theory, stochastic-process

**The problem**: Find the estimated lifetime of an object (e.g. the time it is written next) or the corresponding PDF. This is known as a [renewal process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renewal_theory).

**Constraint**: it is infeasible to track metadata for every single object

**Assumptions**: Prediction inaccuracies for low-volume objects are permissible but inaccuracy should decrease with increasing popularity of an object

Do you have any ideas how these predictions could be achieved, possibly through the use of [sketch data structures](http://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/05/01/probabilistic-structures-web-analytics-data-mining/) (Bloom filters, Count-min sketches, etc.) or forms of sampling (e.g. [exponentially-biased reservoir sampling](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1164180))? Would assuming a specific stochastic process (e.g. a Poisson process) make the problem easier to solve?

A colorful example of this problem would be: *estimate when a user will next visit your site / click something, without being able to track the history of every user*.

Comment: You will have to do some sampling for some objects. If only to help you answer all the questions in your second paragraph. 

To use your colorful example: You need to track some users visits and some click history to make the estimate.